# Eclipse copies heavy resources all the time

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, m2eclipse, m2e

I have some heavy resource files in my project which I need to package in the jar.

I use eclipse as my IDE and it's been very slow since every change I make results in eclipse rebuilding the project, which copies the resources to target folder.

I've tried executing the resources plugin on prepare-package phase but it seems to be executed anyway.

What can I do with it?

Comment: afaik eclipse has its own way of building a maven project. You can always disable the "build automatically" setting, but i guess that's not really solving the problem. But it might help during development.

Comment: It can help sometimes but at most times I want eclipse to at least compile the sources and look for errors

Comment: In your Eclipse project, under Build Path, remove (or at least Exclude) your resources from the build path.

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest using a Maven profile.
So you can:

- Move all your resources inside a profile (i.e. by default, you have no resources; but when you activate your profile, they become available).
- Activate the mentioned profile only when you package the jar; in all other situations (i.e. when Eclipse builds) it is disabled.